# Maven perform error : SCM

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

I use **maven-3.2.3** for my project.

When I execute `mvn release:prepare`, everything is going well.

but after execute `mvn release:perform` I have following error :

***No SCM URL was provided to perform the release from***

I have scm element in my pom.xml :

```xml
<scm>
    <url>scm:git:http://my-project-url/</url>
    <connection>scm:git:http://my-project-url/</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:http://my-project-url/</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

I dont understand why an error of SCM

Comment: Please show the full pom file...

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html) your `<url>` tag is incorrect. It should be simply `http`, without `scm:git`.

Comment: thanks for your response, but It worked earlier. I think there is no problem for url format